# Cross product terms integrate to zero. How?

Tags: integration, statistics

I'm studying a proof involving mixture distributions and a step in the proof is not making sense to me.

It starts with the variance of X, a continuous random variable. Here $E(X)=\bar{\mu}=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i \mu_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i =1$ and each $\mu_i$ is the respective mean for the pdfs we are mixing ( the $f_i(x)$)

$var(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i \int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-\bar{\mu})^2f_i(x)dx$

we introduce $0=\mu_i-\mu_i$ to the integral and group the terms.

$var(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i \int_{\mathbb{R}}(x- \mu_i-\mu_i+  \bar{\mu})^2f_i(x)dx$

$var(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i \int_{\mathbb{R}}((x- \mu_i)- (\mu_i -  \bar{\mu}))^2f_i(x)dx$

Then the next step is:

$var(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i \int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-\mu)^2f_i(x)dx + \sum_{i=1}^k p_i (\mu-\bar{\mu})^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_i(x)dx$

Because "the cross product terms integrate to zero."

So I assume this means:
 $\int_{\mathbb{R}}2(x-\mu_i)(\mu_i-\bar{\mu})f_i(x)dx=0$?

I tried moving out unrelated constants:

$2(\mu_i-\bar{\mu})\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-\mu_i)f_i(x)dx=0$?

Why is this integral zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-\mu_i)f_i(x)dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_i(x)dx -
 \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu_if_i(x)dx \\
&= \mu_i - \mu_i\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_i(x)dx \\
&= \mu_i - \mu_i\cdot 1 \\
&=0.
\end{align}

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} (x-\mu_i) \, f_i(x) \, dx &= \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, f_i(x) \, dx}_{=\mu_i} - \mu_i \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}}  f_i(x) \, dx}_{=1} \\
&= \mu_i - \mu_i \cdot 1 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}